# dropdown menu closes when clicked twice

Tags: javascript, html, css, drop-down-menu, menu

I have a menu that has two options, within each of those options (top left and top right), a dropdown menu pops up, (for top left there is surface and precipitation, and for top right there is submenu 1), when clicking on surface and precipitation, two sub-dropdown options show up for users to select, if you are to click on the top one twice, (surafce 1), for some reason surface 2 disappears. This behavior only shows up when there are two options to click. when clicking top right, submenu 1, option 1, the behavior acts like normal

```js
    var dropdowns = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");

    for (var i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      dropdowns[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var submenuContainer = this.querySelector(".dropdown-container");
        if (submenuContainer.style.display === "block") {
          submenuContainer.style.display = "none";
        } else {
          submenuContainer.style.display = "block";
        }

        var allSubmenuContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container");
        for (var j = 0; j < allSubmenuContainers.length; j++) {
          if (allSubmenuContainers[j] !== submenuContainer) {
            allSubmenuContainers[j].style.display = "none";
          }
        }

        var dropdownOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown a");
        for (var m = 0; m < dropdownOptions.length; m++) {
          dropdownOptions[m].classList.remove("active");
        }

        this.querySelector("a").classList.add("active");
      });
    }

    var submenuOptions = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu a");
    for (var i = 0; i < submenuOptions.length; i++) {
      submenuOptions[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();

        var submenuContainer = this.nextElementSibling;
        var isSubmenuVisible = submenuContainer.style.display === "block";

        var openSubmenuContainers = this.parentElement.querySelectorAll(".submenu-container");
        for (var j = 0; j < openSubmenuContainers.length; j++) {
          if (openSubmenuContainers[j] !== submenuContainer) {
            openSubmenuContainers[j].style.display = "none";
            openSubmenuContainers[j].previousElementSibling.classList.remove("active");
          }
        }

        if (!isSubmenuVisible) {
          submenuContainer.style.display = "block";
          this.classList.add("active");
        } else {
          submenuContainer.style.display = "none";
          this.classList.remove("active");
        }
      });
    }

    var hideSubmenu = function (event) {
      var isClickInsideDropdown = false;
      var element = event.target;
      while (element) {
        if (element.classList && element.classList.contains("dropdown")) {
          isClickInsideDropdown = true;
          break;
        }
        element = element.parentNode;
      }
      if (!isClickInsideDropdown) {
        var allSubmenuContainers = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-container");
        for (var j = 0; j < allSubmenuContainers.length; j++) {
          allSubmenuContainers[j].style.display = "none";
        }
      }
    };

    document.addEventListener("click", hideSubmenu);

    var dropdownMenus = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-menu");
    for (var i = 0; i < dropdownMenus.length; i++) {
      dropdownMenus[i].addEventListener("click", function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
      });
    }

    var firstDropdown = document.querySelector(".dropdown");
    var firstSubmenuContainer = firstDropdown.querySelector(".dropdown-container");
    firstSubmenuContainer.style.display = "block";
```

```css
    ul {
      list-style: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      overflow: hidden;
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    li {
      list-style: none;
      float: left;
    }

    li a,
    .dropdown-btn {
      display: inline-block;
      color: #666;
      text-align: center;
      padding: 14px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      position: relative;
    }

    li a:hover,
    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-btn {
      background-color: #ddd;
    }

    .dropdown-container {
      display: none;
      position: absolute;
      top: 4.2vw;
      left: 3.2vw; /* Update this line */
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      min-width: 24vw;
      box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
      z-index: 1;
    }

    .dropdown-container a {
      color: black;
      padding: 12px 16px;
      text-decoration: none;
      display: block;
    }

      .dropdown-container a:hover {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

    .active {
      background-color: #f1f1f1;
    }

.submenu-container a {
  color: black;
  padding: 1px 1px; /* Adjust the padding values as desired */
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}
      
.submenu-container {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
  <ul>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#" class="active">Top Left</a>
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a href="#" >Surface and Precipitation</a>
          <div class="submenu-container">
            <a href="#" >Surface 1</a>
              <a href="#" >Surface 2</a>
          </div>
      </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown">
      <a href="#">Top Right</a>
      <div class="dropdown-container">
        <div class="dropdown-menu">
          <a href="#" class="submenu-option">Submenu 1</a>
          <div class="submenu-container">
            <a href="#">Submenu 1 Option 1</a>
          </div>
      </div>
          </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```